# Processing HDFS files using the Spark Streaming Job :java

Tags: java, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am trying to process JSON files under HDFS directory(For testing i am using my local windows directory).

The issue is the files are not being consumed and new files are not being identified. Here is the code which i am trying to execute

```
    public class SparkConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            execute();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void execute() throws InterruptedException {
        Function0<JavaStreamingContext> createContextFunc = new Function0<JavaStreamingContext>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public JavaStreamingContext call() {
                return createContext();
            }
        };

        JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/data/cdx_checkpoint", createContextFunc);

        // TODO write logic to read from HDFS and Merge JSON's.

        JavaPairInputDStream<LongWritable,Text> hdfsDstream = streamingContext
                .fileStream("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/data", LongWritable.class , Text.class, TextInputFormat.class);
        hdfsDstream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<LongWritable,Text>>(){

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void call(JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, Text> arg0)
                    throws Exception {
                System.out.println(arg0.countByValue().size());
                arg0.checkpoint();

            }


        });

        streamingContext.start();
        streamingContext.awaitTermination();

    }

    private static JavaStreamingContext createContext() {
        final SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-Spark-Streaming-Application").setMaster("local[*]");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true");
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
        ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/data/cdx_checkpoint");

        return ssc;
    }

}
```

My question boils down to the way i can consume the files under a directory and also keeping a check on latest directories and process them.

The sample json files are copied to the HDFS directory as plain text files. But i am not able to see any logs related to accessing the files.

Comment: did you check the UI on whats happening to the job..whether the job is running fine, or if there are any exceptions,job and stage details etc...

Comment: @KiranBalakrishnan There are no exceptions and job started without any issues. BTW, can i use a local windows directory in textFileStream() ?

Comment: when using file stream it should be a hadoop compatible file system